# Проблемы с urllib. Python

Tags: python, сеть, парсер

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь написать программу, которая бы заходила на аккаунт браузерной игры и выводила бы данные о персонаже.

```
import urllib
import string

url = "http://darkorbit.bigpoint.com/?locale=ru&aid=0" # Адрес на который нужно отправить данные 
login = raw_input("login:") 
password = raw_input("password:") 
data = [("loginForm_default_username",login),("loginForm_default_password",password)]
data_enc = urllib.urlencode(data)
result = urllib.urlopen(url,data_enc)  # Отправляем данные

string = result.read() # Записываем html код полученной страницы в string
position1 = string.find('<a class="verweis" href=',0) + 25 # Выбираем
position2 = string.find('>',position1) - 1 # игровой сервер
url = string[position1:position2] # получаем конечный адрес.
# Если скопировать этот адрес в браузер то откроеться страничка персонажа

result = urllib.urlopen(url) # Но если открыть этот адрес тут
s = result.read() # то получим html код странички

print s # "Неправильный логин или пароль"
```

Насколько я понимаю, в браузере происходит редирект. Как сделать то же на python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The geturl() method returns the real
> URL of the page. In some cases, the
> HTTP server redirects a client to
> another URL. The urlopen() function
> handles this transparently, but in
> some cases the caller needs to know
> which URL the client was redirected
> to. The geturl() method can be used to
> get at this redirected URL.

Т.е. в вашем случае нужно вытащить URL редиректа:

```
result = urllib.urlopen(url)     
s =  urllib.urlopen(result.geturl()).read()
```

Comment: К сожалению не получилось. result.geturl() возвращает ссылку на страницу с ошибкой. Значит сервер каким либо образом "узнал" что используется не браузер? Или я копаю не в ту сторону?

Comment: Нет, браузер/не браузер не причем, в заголовки что угодно можно всунуть. Значит, вы что-то изначально делаете ошибочно, и вас редиректит на описание ошибки. Может, вам нужны какие-то кукисы и т.д.  
Тот код, что я описал, проверил на редиректе - он рабочий.

Comment: Сделал urllib.urlopen(result.geturl()).info()


Date: Sat, 08 Oct 2011 18:32:44 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: dosid=031ab6b5023feec5012e38bc43ce74fb; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Set-Cookie: gameapi_console=0; expires=Sat, 08-Oct-2011 17:32:44 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: es
X-XTM-Node: pool-39-www-011071
Connection: Close

Это может как нибудь помочь? Я лично сомневаюсь над "Vary". Что это?